# BouncyCastle FIPS mode - check SSL certificate revocation using CRLDP

Tags: java, ssl, bouncycastle, certificate-revocation

I am using bouncyCastle library with FIPS mode enabled for SSL communication. So, I have only 3 providers in java.security file as follows:

```
security.provider.1=org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider
security.provider.2=org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.BouncyCastleJsseProvider fips:BCFIPS
security.provider.3=SUN
```

I have written a simple program to test connection with one of our sites:

```
// enable revocation check
System.setProperty("com.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation", "true");
// enable CDP
System.setProperty("com.sun.security.enableCRLDP", "true");
System.setProperty("org.bouncycastle.x509.enableCRLDP", "true");
// disable OCSP
Security.setProperty("ocsp.enable", "false");

URL url = new URL("<my-web-site>");
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.connect();
```

However the connection is failing with following error:

```
org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsFatalAlert: certificate_unknown(46)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLSocketDirect.checkServerTrusted(ProvSSLSocketDirect.java:134)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvTlsClient$1.notifyServerCertificate(ProvTlsClient.java:335)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsUtils.processServerCertificate(TlsUtils.java:4544)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsClientProtocol.handleServerCertificate(TlsClientProtocol.java:842)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsClientProtocol.handleHandshakeMessage(TlsClientProtocol.java:728)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.processHandshakeQueue(TlsProtocol.java:652)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.processRecord(TlsProtocol.java:548)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.RecordStream.readRecord(RecordStream.java:232)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.safeReadRecord(TlsProtocol.java:800)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.blockForHandshake(TlsProtocol.java:396)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsClientProtocol.connect(TlsClientProtocol.java:91)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLSocketDirect.startHandshake(ProvSSLSocketDirect.java:430)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLSocketDirect.startHandshake(ProvSSLSocketDirect.java:411)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:171)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:142)
    at com.test.TestConnection.main(TestConnection.java:153)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Unable to construct a valid chain
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvX509TrustManager.validateChain(ProvX509TrustManager.java:308)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvX509TrustManager.checkTrusted(ProvX509TrustManager.java:267)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(ProvX509TrustManager.java:174)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLSocketDirect.checkServerTrusted(ProvSSLSocketDirect.java:130)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: Certification path could not be validated.
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.PKIXCertPathBuilderSpi.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvX509TrustManager.buildCertPath(ProvX509TrustManager.java:240)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvX509TrustManager.validateChain(ProvX509TrustManager.java:295)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: No CRLs found for issuer "CN=Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2, O="Starfield Technologies, Inc.", L=Scottsdale, ST=Arizona, C=US"
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.RFC3280CertPathUtilities.processCertA(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.PKIXCertPathBuilderSpi.build(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.PKIXCertPathBuilderSpi.build(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.PKIXCertPathBuilderSpi.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.AnnotatedException: No CRLs found for issuer "CN=Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2, O="Starfield Technologies, Inc.", L=Scottsdale, ST=Arizona, C=US"
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.CertPathValidatorUtilities.getCompleteCRLs(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.RFC3280CertPathUtilities.checkCRL(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.RFC3280CertPathUtilities.checkCRLs(Unknown Source)
    ... 28 more
```

I have checked that a valid CRLDP is configured in each of the certificate in certificate chain. Here is how certificate chain looks like (The blue-highlighted CA certificate is present in my JDK truststore) :

[image]

The same code is working fine (connection successful) WITHOUT bouncyCastle (using default JDK providers). However, to make it work with bouncyCastle, I need to put entire certificate chain into my truststore (including end-entity certificate) - which is quite impractical.

Can anyone help me figuring out the problem here?